# .htaccess Redirect based on HTTP_REFERER being empty

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set up a redirect on a WP blog installation that will detect anyone coming in from nowhere (i.e. not from another site). The idea is to trap some of the spambots that plug pre-constructed URLs into the system to create comments/posts. I figure if they don't have a referrer site, I can pop them back to the homepage (www.domain.com/index.php or just www.domain.com), which should mess with the bots but not with real people.

I understand that the referrers can be forged but hopefully it'll stop the stupids, at least.

I have very little clue about .htaccess rewrite rules (I apologise for being a noob), but I couldn't find one that did this in existing answers or anywhere else online, despite several searches. Either no one's done it or I'm not phrasing correctly.

Any help appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against this. By doing it, you may annoy and alienate a portion of potential your users: for example my browser is set not to report referer information, others use anonymity networks. The dump bots you can catch by matching their reported user agent string (as seen [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/blocking-bad-bots-and-scrapers-with-htaccess.html)).

Otherwise it's simple: match against the HTTP_REFERER environmental variable in a RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/
```

The RewriteCond checks to see if the referer is an empty string; the RewriteRule redirects everything to http://example.com/ root. This is a hard redirect, meaning that the server will issue an R=301 moved permanently header. If you just want to sneakily serve another resource, use a soft redirect by specifying a relative URL, like `RewriteRule .* index.php`. However, it may be kinder for people not reporting referrer information to redirect them to a page saying something like "You should enable referrer reporting if you want to read this page".

For more examples on such things, see [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images). There's a very similar prevent-hotlinking method there.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I'm tempted to do the simple version because it's purely a redirect to the homepage: it doesn't transfer them anywhere really bad, annoying or otherwise grrr-inducing. I've bookmarked all that scary bot code, though. I may give that a try first and see if it stops them, then do the other if it doesn't. Again, thanks for an informative, useful answer. Awesome!

Edit: Just spotted the endless loop potential (no reported redirect from browser, even on site). Bah. Time for the extra page as suggested, thank you!